# Firebase equalTo gives old values

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I get all the data from the database without any query, I get the last entries from the database (keys are generated to work this way). Something like this:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('myObj').limitToFirst(100);
ref.on("value", function(snap){
    console.log(snap.val());
});
```

This way I get all the objects I need ordered properly. But if I add a query to filter some data, I lost the order from the original.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('myObj').orderByChild('myChild').equalTo('myproperty').limitToFirst(100);
ref.on("value", function(snap){
    console.log(snap.val());
});
```

This way I am not receiving the most recent data as I get when I don't apply any filter.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Can't you fetch the data first, and then apply the filters?

Comment: It is a huge amount of data, I prefer doing it server side

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to order/filter on two properties, which is not possible with the Firebase Realtime Database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen as far as I know I'm trying to filter for a single property.. I don't understand why are you saying that

Comment: The first snippet you show has an implicit `orderByPriority()/orderByKey()` operation.
In your second snippet, you explicitly order/filter by `myChild` and then seem to be expecting it to order the results by key. That requires two ordering operations, which can't be done on the server.

Comment: But if I'm not wrong "equalTo" operator needs the previews orderByChild operation in order to know which attribute am I ordering. So its the same as saying that filtered data losts the default order? Because I only want to filter for one attribute and get the data at the default order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realised what happens with this:

```
.ref('myObj').orderByChild('myChild').limitToFirst(100);
```

is that `orderByChild('myChild')` reads JSON in descending order (from the bottom) and then that list is queried again by `limitToFirst(100)` in ascending order ("queried again" - I mean maybe in a more efficient way than literally querying list again). So what was originally at the bottom, goes to the top - you get your 100 records starting from the bottom of your Firebase JSON file.

You can try it out ([tested with AngularFire2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularfire-db-api-mgxny2?file=app/app.component.ts) - remove `orderByChild('size')` to see the change in ordering).

Some ways to revert the order:

**First way as you wrote, is simply change query to `LimitToLast()`**

Other ways:

**Revert pipe:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of listObservable | async | reverse">
```

**Using AngularFre2, you could take advantige of Rxjs features:**

```
this.stories = af.database.list('/myObj', {
  query: {
    limitToLast: 100
  }
}).map((array) => array.reverse()) as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
```

**Or one, *interesting*, way to reverse via CSS:**

```
#container{
  display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -moz-flex;
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: -o-flex;  
        -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
        -moz-flex-direction: column-reverse;
        -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse;
        -o-flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Comment: it just works for me changing `limitToFirst` by `limitToLast` i don't need to do anything more. Thanks for pointing me to the correct direction!

Comment: @cor - I just realised what was the cause of this - you can read update answer. Please comment if you find something not right